# Sort list by another list in Python without merging

Tags: python, list, sorting

Note: I understand this looks similar to a lot of questions, but wait just a second and finish reading.

Is there a way to sort a list by another where we do not have to merge the lists somehow?

```
items = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
minutes_ago = [1, 3, 2, 5, 4]
```

Result should be that the `items` are sorted by the `minutes_ago` list. What's the optimised way to do so?

I was thinking of some `sorted(items, key = lambda ... )` but then couldn't imagine how to solve it nicely.

Out:

```
items = ["a", "c", "b", "e", "d"]
```

Comment: Why don't you want to merge them? (and then unmerge them after)

Comment: Performance reasons. I cannot believe that the best we can do in python is to merge the lists.

Comment: Well you have to have *some* data structure that relates the items of the first list to the items of the other, that works in a sorting algorithm, that just tries to compare item. A list of tuples is a pretty natural way to do that.

Comment: I agree, but in this case I really don't need them to be merged, and I'm only interested in "items" as output. I guess `zip` is the simple answer though.

Comment: Fair enough. Even though I came from a different perspective, the current best answer was also given on the simpler question "how to sort a list by another". Duplicate it is.

Comment: Another option would be to create an index list: `ndx = range(len(items)); print([items[n] for n in sorted(ndx, key=lambda x: minutes_ago[x])])`

Answer (score 3):

This is the simplest way I can think of:

```
In [1]: items = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]

In [2]: minutes_ago = [1, 3, 2, 5, 4]

In [3]: [i for m, i in sorted(zip(minutes_ago, items))]
Out[3]: ['a', 'c', 'b', 'e', 'd']
```

Comment: This is what I was thinking of as well. The old decorate/sort/undecorate pattern.

Comment: I guess zipping does not technically merge them, so yea this is a simple answer.